# How to find leaks in Python ctypes libraries

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, ctypes

I'm working on a Python application which uses a number of open source third-party libraries.  One of the libraries is based on `ctypes`, and I recently found more than 10 separate memory leaks in it.  The causes of these leaks ranged from circular references on objects with explicit destructors (which [Python can't garbage collect](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage)) to using `c_char_p` as a return type for functions returning non-const character arrays (resulting in the character arrays being converted automatically to Python strings and the original C-allocated arrays never being freed.)

I fixed the leaks I found and submitted a pull request to the author of the library.  I've done some extremely informal testing by creating and deleting objects in a loop and watching Python's memory usage as I do so, and I think I've found all the leaks.  However, as I'm planning to use this library in an application that I'd like to open source and hopefully have a few other people use, I'd like to be more sure than that.  So my question is: **is there a systematic way to find memory leaks in `ctypes`-based libraries?**

During the process of fixing the leaks I've already found, I tried [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) and [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) but neither were particularly useful for this purpose.  As far as I can tell, both of them will only show objects allocated on the Python heap, so they're of no use in finding leaks caused by improper handling of heap space allocated by C libraries.  Is there a tool I can use in Python that can show me allocations on the C heap, and preferably also which Python objects, if any, refer to the allocated addresses?

Comment: Any luck with this so far Mitch? Did you end up finding an alternate solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't had a chance to try it yet. I did find this suppression file, though, which should help once I get around to trying it: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/valgrind-python.supp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try running the application under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  Valgrind's a useful tool for profiling memory use in compiled applications. This will at least detect the links and report their source.

You will certainly get false positives from Python calls.  Check out [this site](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto) for a nice description of how to use suppressions, which allow you to specifically ignore certain types of errors.  See also [Python's premade list of suppressions (here),](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/valgrind-python.supp) and a [description of why they are needed (here)](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind).

Comment: It has been my (limited) experience that Valgrind doesn't really work on code that goes through python.  A smarter Valgrind user might have better luck however.

Comment: It is true that Valgrind picks up many Python internal calls as "leaks" (especially dist and list instantiation and copying).  However, with proper suppressions, I've been able to find problems in external libraries called by Python code.

Comment: Valgrind briefly occurred to me, but I figured it would produce too many false positives to be useful. However, as there have been no other suggestions, it seems like it might be my best bet...